# rails class in folder and module inclusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, module, include

I have a class Bar in a folder "models/Foo/" called:

```
class Foo::Bar
```

So Bar is in module Foo.

But if I make a file to define module Foo like this:

```
module Foo
  def baz
  end
end
```

method baz is undefined if I try:

```
Foo::Bar.new.baz
```

Why? how it works? How I have to?

Comment: Where do you make that file you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

The point is, Rails doesn't necessary requires all the files in the project. Yes, it is true - you can *reopen* module in Ruby, however you still need to load it somehow.

There's also another mistake you've made. Even if you define a class inside of a module, that class won't have module's methods. In order to add module's functionality to class, you need to *include* or *extend* class with that module.

Here's a couple of links you would find useful:

1. [Ruby Tutorial: Modules](https://thenewcircle.com/static/bookshelf/ruby_tutorial/modules.html) - quite simple tutorial about modules.
2. [Rails autoloading — how it works, and when it doesn't](http://urbanautomaton.com/blog/2013/08/27/rails-autoloading-hell/) - it will help you to understand how and when Rails loads classes.

Hope it helps!